# How can I delete the default constructor for a C++/CLI class?

Tags: constructor, c++-cli, destructor

I have a set of C++/CLI classes I've written as wrappers to native C++ classes. For the C++/CLI classes: I placed the constructor declarations inside the private section of the class declarations and did not implement them, however this leads to linker errors in every case where I have an unimplemented constructor.

What is the appropriate way to delete the default constructor in C++/CLI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works in native C++ because it uses a linker.  Which is happy with a missing member implementation if nobody asks for it.  But that doesn't work in managed code, it doesn't use a linker.  Your class definition is copied into the assembly metadata and binding happens dynamically at runtime.

Which requires all declared members to have a representation, the metadata would otherwise be incomplete and that's not supported since that would break reflection.  Even for private members.  Nothing particularly difficult to solve, `{}` is a perfectly good implementation for a private constructor.

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks. However, I have a reference as a member that I initialize in my custom constructor - this is part of why I want to explicitly disallow default construction. I can't use an empty body implementation because that would not initialize the reference and causes a different compilation error. I can change to using a pointer, if that's the only way I can accomplish this. Is there no other way to disable the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

> I placed the constructor and destructor declarations inside the private section of the class declarations **and did not implement them**, however this leads to linker errors in every case where I have an unimplemented constructor or destructor.

Just because you make the constructor private does not mean you no longer have to implement them.  You're still calling it; you have to implement it.

Comment: Technically, no, I'm not calling it - specifically because I don't want to allow it to be called. In standard C++, this is acceptable, but it seems not to be in C++/CLI. I'm searching for a way to disallow it that *is* valid for C++/CLI.

Comment: @SionSheevok: Ah, ok, I'm not a C++/CLI expert.  Why can't you simply implement it?  It's private, so what does it matter?  Just throw a `{}` in there and be done with it

Comment: Because I have a member in the managed class that is a reference to the native class - references *must* be initialized. I have nothing to initialize the reference with in the default constructor and it doesn't make sense to do so. This is purely a wrapper class to already existing native objects of the native class.

Yes, I can use a pointer instead so that I can use an empty body. I will do this if there is no other choice, but I'd like to know if there is a proper way to do this in C++/CLI, kind of like the delete keyword in C++11.

Comment: @SionSheevok: Yeah, I've written one C++/CLI app (just a managed wrapper for a CCD camera interface) and I had to make some trade-offs like this.  I recall using pointers.  It may not be optimal (though, depending on how that reference is initialized, you may face a similar issue with storing an invalid reference), but sometimes you don't have a choice.  With a proper design you can ensure it is safe.

Comment: Aye. It's more appropriate to not have a default constructor at all in my case, but if there's no other choice, I'll settle for changing it to a pointer and having a dummy, hidden default constructor.